# How to execute UFT Scripts in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, hp-uft

We have around 5000 UFT Web scripts, and we want to execute them in parallel. How can we do it?

Purchasing of parallel threads has been tried, it wasn't cost effective.

Comment: We use multiple virtual machines for pararell execution. What do you mean by "parallel threads"? As i renember you can only open 1 instance of uft per Desktop.

Comment: hi @MapReduce, Appreciate your help. UFT team is providing parallel threads for purchase. Like what you said opening another instance in another machine. I am expecting something similar to selenium. Same machine with parallel execution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seems like you need to have concurrent licenses in order to execute tests in parallel. Also one execution consumes 1 concurrent license. [More Info](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Application-Delivery-Management/Accelerate-web-testing-with-parallel-execution-in-UFT-14-50/ba-p/1662982).  Uft also brings an good Documentation on how to use the Parallel Runner: [Using the Parallel Runner](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.52/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/parallel-test-runs.htm#mt-item-1)